# Why is this finally not executing?

Tags: c#

.net 4 console app sample

When I run this in the vs 2010 it seems to keep throwing (from the catch) and never gets to the finally. It breaks on the throw and shows the exception, I hit f5 and it rethrows almost like its looping on the throw. Using similiar code in another exe I was able to throw the exception to the console and execute the finally to clean up. That is not the case not and I'm wondering why.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception");
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Catch");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finally");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should write "Catch", then "Finally", then crash because of the exception. Isn't it what happens?

Comment: Its looping because within your catch statement your throwing the same exception.

Comment: @ramhound er, no, once you are in a `catch`, then the throwing doesn't put you back to the start of that `catch` section!

Answer (score 10):

On the contrary, it does execute the `finally` block. This is the output:

```
Catch

Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Exception at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 24
Finally
```

Comment: I agree, I see the same results.

Answer (score 2):

I would bet the finally actually is executed, but being in the Main method of the console application, in the finally the console object is not available anymore.

Comment: In my test, adding a breakpoint shows that this is the case - it definitely hits the finally. Maybe the console has stopped listening by this point.

Answer (score 2):

If I start the program with debugging, the code stops with the message "unhandled exception", which is before finally would be executed. Running without debugging will work as intended (CTRL-F5).

Using the debugger you can verify the finally being executed by moving your testcode inside another try-catch block, e.g.:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{      
    try
    {
        Method();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("caught in main");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
public static void Method()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Catch");
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finally");
    }
}
```

Comment: I had no problem breaking in the finally block in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can guarantee that it is indeed executing, as @David Heffernan demonstrated with his output; however, you might consider what is said in the C# specification (8.10) in order be confident that is should be:

> The statements of a finally block are always executed when control
>   leaves a try statement. This is true whether the control transfer
>   occurs as a result of normal execution, as a result of executing a
>   break, continue, goto, or return statement, or as a result of
>   propagating an exception out of the try statement.